# Is it okay for a summer student to request a department transfer?

Tags: internal-transfer

I am a returning student and my job requires me to be outdoors. The new medication I have (new to this work season) is causing me to overheat and its quite bad. My doctor says I am okay if I want to keep this job, but honestly, I don't.

Would I be wrong to request a transfer? I have been told (by someone not from work) that I will probably not get the transfer, get fired for not being able to do the job, and if I don't, I'll never get references from them or be hired back next summer for a different job, since they would have one less worker for what I was hired for.

Comment: Well it seems you would rather not have a job then work outdoors... so request the transfer.  If they throw a fit you quit and pretend you never held the job in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

> Would I be wrong to request a transfer?

**Not at all**

Jobs are important because they provide income which is needed to live. However, health and well being take precedence over this. You should request the transfer regardless of the possible outcomes (getting fired).

This is all stated ignoring the fact that you really don't want the job at all. You may want to reflect on the personal aspect of why you don't want to return to this job; if it's just about your medication or something else.